# How can I get a shell script to change directory for me?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

here is a small test I ran, to try and move me back to root:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
cd /
pwd
```

It returns the current working directory, and then the correct new one, but when the script finished executing, I am still in the original directory and haven't moved. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Cheers Michael!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to achieve this within a script - scripts start subshell, which is a standalone environment. There's all sorts of reasons for this, but pretty fundamentally - a script cannot tamper with *your* environment (including your `cwd`).

The closest you get is creating an alias within the *current* shell.

```
alias chr="cd /"
```

Either that, or 'source' the script, it "runs" in the current shell. E.g. like your `.bashrc`.